# Thrown die statistics

Tags: probability

A die is thrown 500 times.  What is the likelihood that the pattern of the first 5 throws is duplicated somewhere down string?  MIght you supply the expression for the solution?  Thanks,

David Ross

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 0):

Let's divide the string into (overlapping, continuous) sub-strings of length 5. There are `500 - 5 = 495` such strings possible (discarding the initial string). Start from the beginning. Put 1 when you find your pattern string and put 0 when sub-string doesn't contain the pattern.

Prob(pattern) = (1/2)*5 = Prob(1)
Prob(0) = 1 - Prob(1)

Your question reduces to "*find the probability that there is one or more 1 present in the 495 strings.*"

Solution : 1 - Prob(no 1 present) == 1 - (Prob(0)^495)